# How to get rid the additional dot at the end of “Appendix A.”?

Tags: koma-script, appendices, cleveref, appendix, section-titles

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{secdot}

\begin{document}

See \cref{aa} for details.

\begin{appendices}

\small
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.}
\crefalias{section}{appendix}

\section{Fancy Title}\label{aa}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

As seen in the screenshot below, the output is the desired one with one exception: the `\cref{aa}` command yields “Appendix A.” when I’d like it to display just “Appendix A” (the final dot should not be there).

[image]

One possibility is to remove the option `[title]` from `\usepackage[title]{appendix}` and change `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.}` for `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}`. However, if I do this, the title “Appendix A” gets lost (as can be seen in the screenshot below):

[image]

**Can anybody help me get rid of the extra dot at the end of “Appendix A.” without losing the word “Appendix”?**

Comment: Why are you removing the `title` option if you want a title?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I’m doing that just to show that removing that option together with getting rid of the dot in `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.}` solves the initial issue but creates a new one (i.e., the lack of a title).

Comment: Using `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}` with passing the `title` option in package declaration should give you "Appendix A" everywhere.

Comment: Thank you again. And sure, you are right. But that’s not the output I desire. I want `Appendix A. Fancy Title` in the title of the section itself and `\cref{aa}` to display `Appendix A` rather than `Appendix A.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using the package `appendix`. (Nor `secdot`!)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

% PACKAGES LOADING
%\usepackage{secdot} % DO NOT LOAD <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\usepackage[title]{appendix} % not used
\usepackage{cleveref} % must be the last

%%*********************************************added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\let\oldappendix\appendix   
\newcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix} % 
\renewcommand\appendix{%    
\oldappendix
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}   
}
%%*********************************************

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

See \cref{aa} for details.

\appendix   
\small

\section{Fancy Title}\label{aa}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is one of those sad situations in which your solution works in my MWE (and therefore solves my question), but it does not work in my true document (only God knows for what reason).

Comment: @Héctor Could you update the MWE? Updated my code, give it a try just in case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The guilty package of this is `\usepackage{secdot}`. Can your answer be adapted to the use of this package? I will update my code accordingly now.

Comment: @Héctor The MWE must use the package! :-}

Comment: Your solution works. PS: I try to make them really minimal, and I thought that that package wouldn’t mind that much. It took time to identify it. I’m sorry. I just updated the MWE.

Comment: @Héctor `secdot` is useless with` Koma script`. Sections already have a dot. Thank you for your feedback.